# fotorama gallery not working inside Swiper slider

Tags: javascript, swiper.js, fotorama

I have a slider set up with [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/). The slides contain HTML and a photo gallery slider that is created with [fotorama](https://fotorama.io). The problem that I am having is that there seems to be some conflict between Swiper and fotorama so the fotorama photo gallery slider does not work.

Here is a demo of the problem:

http://sww.nz/test/swiper/swiper.html

Originally I started with a different slider, [glider.js](https://nickpiscitelli.github.io/Glider.js/), but I was having difficulty trying to implementing some filtering on the slides so I switched to swiper as it has more built-in functionality to make that that easier. Fotorama worked fine inside the glider slides:

http://sww.nz/test/swiper/glider.html

Any ideas on how to resolve the conflict between swiper and fotorama?

Comment: why not owl carousel

Comment: actually I ended up trying out Slick and fotorama works ok within a Slick slide. Didn't try Owl, don't need to now.